# Using jquery to get values of radio buttons and display text depending on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button

I have this code here http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/302/ everything works fine, until I add second group of radio buttons.

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
    var total = 0;
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("price") !== undefined) {
            total += parseInt($(this).attr("price"));

        } else {
            total += 0;
        }
    });

    if (total === 0) {
        $('.total-price').text('Some new text.');

    } else {
        $('.total-price').text('Total price: $' + total);
    }

});

$("input").click(function (event) {
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        if ($("input:checked").attr("value") == "ownlogo") {
            $('.logo_p').text('Own logo.');
        }

        if ($("input:checked").attr("value") == "textlogo") {
            $('.logo_p').text('Text logo.');
        }

        if ($("input:checked").attr("value") == "Starter") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Strtr price.');
        }

        if ($("input:checked").attr("value") == "Business1") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Business price.');
        }

        if ($("input:checked").attr("value") == "Pro") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Pro price.');
        }

    });

});
```

When I start clicking on second group of buttons - it works, but when I select something from first group, second group stops working.

Please take a look at the script to get the idea of my problem.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(this)` reference in your `.each()` loop. `$("input:checked")` inside the `.each()` loop will simply return the first matched element, That is the problem in your code.

Try,

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "ownlogo") {
            $('.logo_p').text('Own logo.');
        }

        if ($(this).attr("value") == "textlogo") {
            $('.logo_p').text('Text logo.');
        }

        if ($(this).attr("value") == "Starter") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Strtr price.');
        }

        if ($(this).attr("value") == "Business1") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Business price.');
        }

        if ($(this).attr("value") == "Pro") {
            $('.plan_price').text('Pro price.');
        }
    });
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/fQTUp/303/)

Comment: Great! Works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check

```
 if ($('input[name=RadioGroupName]:checked').attr("value") == "textlogo")
```

where RadioGroupName is your radio button group name. In this way you can check your each group separately.

Comment: This should work as well, but having $(this) instead of $('input[name=.....  would be better as I won't need to type in each radio group name.

Comment: ok fine and @Sniurs i think there can be much more better and less code to achieve what you want to.

Comment: I agree, but I have to say I'm quite new to js/jquery. Probably I could use switch/case command to have less code. Your thoughts on this are welcome ;)